# TIZEN STUDIO "An exception occurred (Installing the package... > Fail)"

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-studio

I need help.

I am using the last Tizen Studio update (6.1)
Certificate profile is OK (Author and Distributor made).
Device is installed with the current distributor certificate.
Times are syncronized.
but when i try to run my WEB APP in Device this alert shows:

An exception occurred
(Installing the package... > Fail)
this is the alert:
[image: Install Error]

this is my log:

```
[2023.04.13 08:33:07][ERROR] SchemaBasedValidator.java(117) - Invalid file or path: \schemas\widgets.xsd
[2023.04.13 08:33:07][ERROR] AbstractLibraryLocation.java(111) - C:\tizen-studio\platforms\tizen-6.5\tv-samsung\widlprocxmls\tizen.widlprocxml (O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\tizen-studio\platforms\tizen-6.5\tv-samsung\widlprocxmls\tizen.widlprocxml (O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at org.tizen.web.project.initializer.AbstractLibraryLocation.getDocument(AbstractLibraryLocation.java:141)
at org.tizen.web.project.initializer.AbstractLibraryLocation.convertXmlToJs(AbstractLibraryLocation.java:97)
at org.tizen.web.project.initializer.AbstractLibraryLocation.<init>(AbstractLibraryLocation.java:83)
at org.tizen.web.project.initializer.TizenLibraryInitializer$TizenLibraryLocation.<init>(TizenLibraryInitializer.java:63)
at org.tizen.web.project.initializer.TizenLibraryInitializer$TizenLibraryLocation.getInstance(TizenLibraryInitializer.java:76)
at org.tizen.web.project.initializer.TizenLibraryInitializer.getLibraryLocation(TizenLibraryInitializer.java:96)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.JsGlobalScopeContainerInitializer.getIncludepathEntries(JsGlobalScopeContainerInitializer.java:181)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.containerPutIfInitializingWithSameEntries(JavaModelManager.java:589)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.SetContainerOperation.execute(SetContainerOperation.java:54)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.JavaScriptCore.setJsGlobalScopeContainer(JavaScriptCore.java:3924)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.JsGlobalScopeContainerInitializer.initialize(JsGlobalScopeContainerInitializer.java:85)
at org.tizen.web.project.initializer.AbstractLibraryInitializer.initialize(AbstractLibraryInitializer.java:19)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2216)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager$6.run(JavaModelManager.java:2146)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2240)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2267)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeAllContainers(JavaModelManager.java:2162)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getJsGlobalScopeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1536)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.JavaScriptCore.getJsGlobalScopeContainer(JavaScriptCore.java:1342)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2747)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:2026)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.JavaScriptCore.initializeAfterLoad(JavaScriptCore.java:2678)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.InitializeAfterLoadJob$RealJob.run(InitializeAfterLoadJob.java:32)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
[2023.04.13 08:33:07][ERROR] AbstractLibraryLocation.java(111) - C:\tizen-studio\platforms\tizen-6.5\tv-samsung\widlprocxmls\w3cwidget.widlprocxml (O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\tizen-studio\platforms\tizen-6.5\tv-samsung\widlprocxmls\w3cwidget.widlprocxml (O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at org.tizen.web.project.initializer.AbstractLibraryLocation.getDocument(AbstractLibraryLocation.java:141)
at org.tizen.web.project.initializer.AbstractLibraryLocation.convertXmlToJs(AbstractLibraryLocation.java:97)
at org.tizen.web.project.initializer.AbstractLibraryLocation.<init>(AbstractLibraryLocation.java:83)
at org.tizen.web.project.initializer.W3CLibraryInitializer$W3CLibraryLocation.<init>(W3CLibraryInitializer.java:62)
at org.tizen.web.project.initializer.W3CLibraryInitializer$W3CLibraryLocation.getInstance(W3CLibraryInitializer.java:75)
at org.tizen.web.project.initializer.W3CLibraryInitializer.getLibraryLocation(W3CLibraryInitializer.java:95)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.JsGlobalScopeContainerInitializer.getIncludepathEntries(JsGlobalScopeContainerInitializer.java:181)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.containerPutIfInitializingWithSameEntries(JavaModelManager.java:589)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.SetContainerOperation.execute(SetContainerOperation.java:54)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.JavaScriptCore.setJsGlobalScopeContainer(JavaScriptCore.java:3924)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.JsGlobalScopeContainerInitializer.initialize(JsGlobalScopeContainerInitializer.java:85)
at org.tizen.web.project.initializer.AbstractLibraryInitializer.initialize(AbstractLibraryInitializer.java:19)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2216)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager$6.run(JavaModelManager.java:2146)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2240)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2267)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeAllContainers(JavaModelManager.java:2162)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getJsGlobalScopeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1536)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.JavaScriptCore.getJsGlobalScopeContainer(JavaScriptCore.java:1342)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2747)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:2026)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.JavaScriptCore.initializeAfterLoad(JavaScriptCore.java:2678)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.InitializeAfterLoadJob$RealJob.run(InitializeAfterLoadJob.java:32)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
[2023.04.13 08:33:07][ERROR] AbstractLibraryLocation.java(111) - C:\tizen-studio\platforms\tizen-6.5\tv-samsung\widlprocxmls\html5.widlprocxml (O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\tizen-studio\platforms\tizen-6.5\tv-samsung\widlprocxmls\html5.widlprocxml (O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at org.tizen.web.project.initializer.AbstractLibraryLocation.getDocument(AbstractLibraryLocation.java:141)
at org.tizen.web.project.initializer.AbstractLibraryLocation.convertXmlToJs(AbstractLibraryLocation.java:97)
at org.tizen.web.project.initializer.AbstractLibraryLocation.<init>(AbstractLibraryLocation.java:83)
at org.tizen.web.project.initializer.HTML5LibraryInitializer$HTML5LibraryLocation.<init>(HTML5LibraryInitializer.java:62)
at org.tizen.web.project.initializer.HTML5LibraryInitializer$HTML5LibraryLocation.getInstance(HTML5LibraryInitializer.java:75)
at org.tizen.web.project.initializer.HTML5LibraryInitializer.getLibraryLocation(HTML5LibraryInitializer.java:95)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.JsGlobalScopeContainerInitializer.getIncludepathEntries(JsGlobalScopeContainerInitializer.java:181)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.containerPutIfInitializingWithSameEntries(JavaModelManager.java:589)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.SetContainerOperation.execute(SetContainerOperation.java:54)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.JavaScriptCore.setJsGlobalScopeContainer(JavaScriptCore.java:3924)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.JsGlobalScopeContainerInitializer.initialize(JsGlobalScopeContainerInitializer.java:85)
at org.tizen.web.project.initializer.AbstractLibraryInitializer.initialize(AbstractLibraryInitializer.java:19)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2216)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager$6.run(JavaModelManager.java:2146)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2240)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2267)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeAllContainers(JavaModelManager.java:2162)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getJsGlobalScopeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1536)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.JavaScriptCore.getJsGlobalScopeContainer(JavaScriptCore.java:1342)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2747)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:2026)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.JavaScriptCore.initializeAfterLoad(JavaScriptCore.java:2678)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.InitializeAfterLoadJob$RealJob.run(InitializeAfterLoadJob.java:32)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
[2023.04.13 08:33:54][ERROR] SchemaBasedValidator.java(117) - Invalid file or path: \schemas\widgets.xsd
[2023.04.13 08:36:40][ERROR] InstallStep.java(176) - Return Code:1010)Tizen Web Application install failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Happens something similar to me as well, trying to run a native web assembly app on my TV Device.

- First of all, check that you computer and your device are using the same network.
- Check in `Remote Device Manage`r ( from your project, click on the box
  as in the attach image) if your device is connect. [image]
- and the worst for me is this last step.
  From `Tools > Device Manager`,
  right click on your device, and select `Permit to install application`. I am using a Mac M1, and without an external mouse i
  was not able to make right click. Keyboard combo was not working.
  After that I was able to run my app on device

  [image]

Here a link from the docs.
[https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-watch-tizen/getting-certificates/permit.html#:~:text=From%20Tizen%20Studio%202.0%2C%20right,developer%20directory%20of%20the%20device](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-watch-tizen/getting-certificates/permit.html#:%7E:text=From%20Tizen%20Studio%202.0%2C%20right,developer%20directory%20of%20the%20device).

Hope you make it work!

Comment: Thank you. But i follow ALL these Steps Samsung recommends, but does not Work.